# Python console program, the ability to position text in the console

Tags: python, console

I wanted to write a short python console program that would retrieve the Btc price from bitbay and binance every 10 seconds. All in all, I wrote, but I would like the reading result to appear in the same place on the console all the time, and not to print a line under the line. Is there such a possibility in python? Because in C # it exists.
I can't find such information anywhere, can anyone help and explain to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short example using end='\r' in a for loop:

```
import time
for num in range(10):
    print(num, end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
```

When you go to print the price, use the end='\r' argument. In this case, the output will show a single int at a time instead of showing all the numbers up to 10.